# How to use subtype discriminators in enhanced entity relationship modeling

Tags: oracle, database-design, erd, discriminator, subtype

So the Supertype is Person, with three subtypes (Volunteer, Employee, Donor).
The constraints are as follows:

If a person is an employee then that person *cannot* be a volunteer or a donor. If a person is a donor then that person *can* be a volunteer but *cannot* be an employee.  If a person is a volunteer then that person *can* be a donor but *cannot* be an employee.

I believe it would use the overlap rule, but I am unsure of the attributes to include. Is it just a composite attribute of all three options? E.g. PERSON (Person_Type(Volunteer?,Donor?, Employee?)) -boolean attributes
Or would it also include a simple attribute like the disjoint rule? Where the Person_Type values will be either V (volunteer), D (donor) or E (employee).

Comment: Are there any attributes associated with the subtypes? Are you implementing them as separate (child) tables under the supertype?

Comment: Volunteer, Donor and Employee are all separate tables under Person. Volunteer and Donor don't have attributes but have relationships with one table each. Employee has attributes and is a supertype to two other subtypes. This is simple enough and uses the discriminator's disjoint rule.